# What is the maximum error?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Three positive numbers, each less than 100 are rounded to the first decimal place and then multiplied together, using differential, how I estimate the maximum error?

Answer (score 0):

Say that your numbers are $x,y,z$ and they are multiplied together so $A=x y z$. To me the simplest way is to go through logarithmic differentiation to get $$\frac {\Delta A}{A}=\frac {\Delta x}{x}+\frac {\Delta y}{y}+\frac {\Delta z}{z}$$ and the maximum relative error on $A$ will correspond to $$\left|\frac{\text{$\Delta $x}}{x}\right|+\left|\frac{\text{$\Delta $y}}{y}\right|+\left|\frac{\text{$\Delta $z}}{z}\right|$$ From what you said,$\Delta x=\Delta y=\Delta y=0.05$ (numbers rounded to the fist decimal place). So it seems to me that the maximum error on $A$ is given by $$(\Delta A)_{max}=0.05(xy+xz+yz)$$